who is cooking ? vs who is going to cook?
My grammar book writes like this:

Who's cooking lunch? (asking what has been arranged)
Who's going to cook lunch? (asking about a decision)

I have a context:
For the party tomorrow, I am the director, my employee reported to me the current status of the process, so I know that everything has been arranged, but I don't know who is the cook for the food.
Can I use either way to ask without difference?

Who's cooking ?

Who's going to cook ?



I'm surprised by the book's advice; I think "who's cooking" is also ok when asking for a decision, at least informally.

Yes, it's bad advice. Only one of them can mean "Who is cooking now?" (possibly as the result of an arrangement that has already been put into effect) but both can mean "Who will cook?"

Yes, both of these are idiomatic. The second phrasing more directly refers to a future action, but the first would still be understood in the context of an even that will be happening soon (if not right now).
You could also say, "Who's cooking tomorrow?" to more explicitly refer to the time period. As the speaker gets further removed from the time they're talking about, this phrasing may provide useful context.

this phrasing may provide useful context= > I don't get what you mean here. Can you help me explain more?

@LE123 If I walked into the kitchen and asked "who's cooking?" that might be interpreted to mean right now or in the very near future. Only if we're already talking about plans for dinner tomorrow, or if I explicitly ask "who's cooking tomorrow" would the future time period be understood.
